# Background color slide down

Tags: jquery

I have a list of buttons, and when I hover over them I want a new background color to slide down, I know about the slide() function but how would I apply it to the background color property?

Comment: what are you trying to do?? and which dom background color you want to change ??? any Code??? or html??

Comment: How can you slide a solid colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that jQuery supports animating the background property out of the box. There are plugins that will help you achieve this effect though. Jonathan Snook has an article about it:

- http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

It's from 2008 though so there could be an improvement on this.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this site I made for a client ages ago](http://www.hyperentertainment.com/v1/default.aspx) - I can't even remember how the code works, but essentially it doesn't use background colour, it uses `<div>` elements, absolutely positioned behind each link, and animates them on hover of the associated `<a>` elements.

Comment: That is the effect I want but the buttons are modifiable through a database so I can't use absolute positioning

Answer (score 1):

there are almost endless ways of doing this. Here is a list to check out:

1. http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations
2. http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/
3. http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/background-image-animation-with-jquery-jani/

Just Google jQuery Backgorund image animation, but what they all have in common is that either a child element slides up and down or the background image position is being animated.

I advise you to stay away from the jQuery Color plugin as it sounds like a good idea when you look for things like this, but i think the community will agree with me that it is very buggy unless you go for the full UI library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to slid down a background. You can do this using div-s that behave like buttons or you can try this:

```
   $(buttonselector).css('background-color','red');
```

It's not a slide, but it should change the color.