# How to animate color?

Tags: jquery

I have li elements:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I want to animate color on hover that a new color comes from the bottom.

How to do it?

Comment: Just on text or on the background ?

Comment: Can you link us to an example?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I know how to change the color of the animate but I want to rise up from bottom

Comment: What is that supposed to look like?

Comment: Like a fireplace burning mossy logs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of this [jQuery PlugIn](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) in order to provide animate() capabilities to colors!

Example Usage (copied from github page!)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div {
      background-color:#bada55;
      width:100px;
      border:1px solid green;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.color.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="go">Simple</button>
  <button id="sat">Desaturate</button>
  <div id="block">Hello!</div>
  <script>
    $("#go").click(function(){
      $("#block").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#abcdef"
      }, 1500 );
    });

    $("#sat").click(function(){
      $("#block").animate({
        backgroundColor: $.Color({ saturation: 0 })
      }, 1500 );
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know how to change color, but I do not know how to rise up

Comment: okay, then it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763428/background-color-slide-down or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633115/background-color-property-slide-up

Comment: ok :) But ul->li is auto generated by wordpress nav menu. little ability to modify the code